# Weird error when connecting two objects

Tags: mesh, texturing, objects

I'm trying to connect two objects but when I do it creates some sort of texture error in the middle of the objects. Not sure what's wrong because both the objects seem fine to me. This is after remeshing

Before connecting:
[image]

After connecting:
[image]

Comment: how do you connect them? do you have modifiers on the final object that might affect the geometry?

Comment: I'm connecting them with the bool tool addon by pressing ctrl+shift+numpad(+). I have a cast and subdivision surface modifier applied to each object

Comment: a boolean operation may create a bad topology, you need to correct

Comment: I don't know how this addon works in particular, but it does look like the generated geometry at the seam isn't perfectly respecting the original shape. It is not surprising, it depends on the method used, and you may not always have a choice.